# Getting specific attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have a a href which is formatted as :

```
<a href class='link' location='USA'>USA</a>
```

I'm then using JQuery to try and get the value of location and pass that to a new page.

```
$(".link").click( function() {
   var location = $(this).attr("location").val();
   Popup('open.php?action=region&location=' + location,'open','300','200','yes');return false;
});
```

This isn't working.

I'm not getting the value of location passed.

Can someone advise what I've done wrong !

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly inventing attributes which don't conform to the standard will mean your HTML is invalid which could lead to both UI and JS issues. Use `data` attributes to store custom data in an element:

```
<a href="#" class='link' data-location='USA'>USA</a>
```

You can then access this in your click handler using `data()`:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default link behaviour
    var location = $(this).data("location");
    Popup('open.php?action=region&location=' + location, 'open', '300', '200', 'yes');
    return false;
});
```

Just for your reference, when accessing an attribute of an element via `attr()` you don't need to call `val()` on it, for example:

```
var foo = $("#element").attr("foo"); 
console.log(foo); // = "bar"
```

Comment: The comment on `val()` is really the key here. There's nothing wrong with using `attr()` unless the data are being updated dynamically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr.

Comment: Perfect thanks - I hadn't realised about the `data` attribute,  but I will remember that.. Thanks again